# How to keep selected columns and delete the others?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am a basic user of SQL and started my journey with an ORM. With time I realized that I would be better off using plain SQL.

The thing that I am missing from ORMs is the ability to easily migrate the DB when I add/remove columns.

To that I would like, at initialisation phase, to create or keep only specific columns and remove the others. The DB will already have data, so dropping and recreating it is not a solution.

Is there a standard way to say in SQL

> here is the list of columns you should either create or keep, and remove any others?

Comment: if you use python(django) ORMs  you can just add/remove columns , and then `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate` . without eny problems.

Comment: @BA.JAmar my point was that I moved away from ORMs (specifically from GORM in Go) and wanted to recreate in pure SQL the automigrate functionality

Comment: You can either use CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE… and provide the new table definition (though this will lose any existing data in the table) or you can add/drop columns using ALTER TABLE ADD/DROP …